# Angular5 i18n in combination with ServiceWorker - switching language not allowed by SW

Tags: angular, internationalization, service-worker

I've build my Angular app for different locales using the angular-cli. The builds are in subfolders of this dist folder (e.g. dist/en; dist/en-GB; dist/de). In NodeJS/Express, there is a route per locale (e.g. dist/en/index.html etc).

The webapp is installed using @angular/service-worker

In the app, there is a button per locale to switch the locale/language. It sets the window.location to the desired route. Doing that, the ServiceWorker throws this exception:

`main.f124c1a5779b9c9d8a4d.bundle.js:1 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): SecurityError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: The script resource is behind a redirect, which is disallowed.`

What is the correct way to serve the webapp in the desired locale/language inside a working ServiceWorker? Or how to spin up a new ServiceWorker?

Comment: What is the URL of your Service Worker? Is the URL using a redirect?

Comment: The URL was wrong, it pointed to the root while the ServiceWorker file is in the locale subfolder. This combined with some Express URL mapping solved the issue

Comment: I have the same problem! Where did you change the URL for the `ngsw-worker.js`?